# c# Threading Lock and Monitor

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, monitor

I'm currently running into a problem with multithreading and accessing a static list. A static list holds all items with several properties. The items are identified with a `Guid`. A main work thread changes some properties for any item in the static list. The child threads all have their own `Guid`, with this `Guid` they read their own item in the static list. And after a specific event they remove their assigned element from the static list.

[image]

To get to the source I have broken down my code to the essential methods and classes. The work thread has the following simplified code

```
public void RunWork()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Int32 index = -1;
    while (!Kill)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        if (MainWindow.Clients != null)
        {
            index = random.Next(0, MainWindow.Clients.Count);

            MainWindow.Clients[index].State = MainWindow.RandomString(9);
        }
    }
}
```

Each child thread has the following simplified code

```
public void RunChild()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    while (!Kill)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        if (MainWindow.Clients.Any(x => x.Id == Id))
        {
            this.State = MainWindow.Clients.First(x => x.Id == Id).State;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(50));
        if (random.Next(100) % 90 == 0)
        {
            Kill = true;
            MainWindow.Clients.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == Id);
        }
    }
}
```

If a child removes itself from the `MainWindow.Clients` list the work thread throws a exception, that the index it is trying to access does not exist.

I have added `lock` statments around every access of `MainWindow.Clients` but this does not prevent the work thread from accessing a deleted item. I have also tried `Monitor.Enter(MainWindow.Clients)` and `Monitor.Exit(MainWindow.Clients)` but with the same result as with `lock`.

The static list `MainWindow.Clients` is created before any thread runs and never gets recreated or disposed.

If the `lock` statement is set around this block of code in the `RunWork()` method

```
lock (MainWindow.Clients)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    if (MainWindow.Clients != null)
    {
        index = random.Next(0, MainWindow.Clients.Count);

        MainWindow.Clients[index].State = MainWindow.RandomString(9);
    }
}
```

Why does it not block the child threads from changing the list between the lines 
where the random index is set and the list gets accessed?

**Update 1:**
The following code still throws a IndexOutOfRangeException at `MainWindow.Clients[index].State = MainWindow.RandomString(9);`:

```
public void RunWork()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Int32 index = -1;
    while (!Kill)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        if (MainWindow.Clients != null)
        {
            lock (MainWindow.Clients)
            {
                index = random.Next(0, MainWindow.Clients.Count);

                MainWindow.Clients[index].State = MainWindow.RandomString(9);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void RunChild()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    while (!Kill)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        if (MainWindow.Clients.Any(x => x.Id == Id))
        {
            this.State = MainWindow.Clients.First(x => x.Id == Id).State;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(50));
        if (random.Next(100) % 90 == 0)
        {
            Kill = true;
            lock (MainWindow.Clients)
            {
                MainWindow.Clients.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2:** [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/dzqec5JW) is the complete code for the quick sample application

**Update 3:** I have edited my code and wrapped all accesses of `MainWindow.Clients` with lock statements. But still the threads access the variable while it is locked:
[image]

Comment: Are you putting lock statement at both the places? i.e. in WorkThread before accessing an Index, and at Child/Client Threads when removing the Index? If the inner collection is a Dictionary - use TryGetValue instead of [ ] way. Also try to reduce the size of the lock section... May be wrap the index = random.. .& MainWindow.Clients[] statements into lock

Comment: "Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement  So "lock (MainWindow.Clients)" is not recommended. Declare private Object thisLock = new Object();

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava Yes, I have tried to `lock` (and `Monitor.Enter`) both places.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev I use a `public static List` because the code in that is currently in production is the same. The logic is seperated over several classes and libraries. If I lock a private object will this prevent the access to my public list?

Comment: If you correctly lock in both places and do not access to this list from any other places (hard to be sure since its public static) - it cannot fail with such error any more. Maybe worth showing how exactly do you lock in both places.

Comment: the recommendation is to use object type (not list, form,...) for locking

Comment: @Evk I have updated my answer with my changed code. Still the same exception.

Comment: also you don't lock this.State = MainWindow.Clients.First(x => x.Id == Id).State;

Comment: While your locking is not correct (can lead to other errors) I don't see how it can produce that specific error you mention. And how is MainWindow.Clients defined?

Comment: Could it be that this exception is thrown when the list is empty?
`MainWindow.Clients.Count` is 0, so `random.Next()` returns 0, so `index` will be 0. Trying to get the `[0]`th item from an empty list will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @JoeJoe87577 - Your code looks awfully flaky. What is the requirement that you're trying to solve? (Not what this code is trying to do, but the reason behind this code.)

Comment: @Enigmativity This code is just the simplified problem. The real application has to many dependencies on external services to run in a quick and dirty sample. I've added the complete sample code to my original post.

Comment: @HHLV Yes the list is empty, but in my understanding the lock should prevent any other thread from removing any items as long as the lock is active.

Comment: @JoeJoe87577 The lock will prevent that, but the list can be empty before entering the lock, right?

Comment: @HHLV I've updated my post and my code but the problem still persists.

Comment: In your code you still access `Clients` variable in many places without lock, such as in `btn_addchild_Click`, `lb_clients_MouseDoubleClick` etc

Comment: Do not lock Clients. Create a readonly static field of type object that contains a new object, and lock *only* on that. **Every single access to Clients must be under that lock**. Your code is a mess of bad practices; fix them first.

Comment: @JoeJoe87577 - You didn't answer my question: "What is the requirement that you're trying to solve? (Not what this code is trying to do, but the reason behind this code.)"

Comment: Change to: lb_clients.Clear(); lb_clients.AddRange(Clients); locking before. Check for Clients.Any() before:
index = random.Next(0, Clients.Count);
MainWindow.mainWindow.Clients[index].State = MainWindow.mainWindow.RandomString(9);
Check: https://pastebin.com/J96hBhM5

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I've written something that might help you find the correct solution. Sorry for the lack of correctness   - tight schedule ;-)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConcurrentCollectionTest
{
    internal class Client
    {
        public string State
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
    }

    internal class MainWindow
    {
        private ConcurrentDictionary<int, Client> _dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Client>();

        public IDictionary<int, Client> Clients
        {
            get
            {
                return _dict;
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static bool killAll = false;
        private static MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        private static int id = -100;
        private static string state = "Initial";
        private static Random random = new Random();
        private static object lockObject = new object();

        internal static string RandomString(int v)
        {
            int k = random.Next(0, v);
            return k.ToString();
        }

        public static void RunChild()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"child running {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}");
            bool killThis = false;
            while (!killThis && !killAll)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Client client = null;
                if (mainWindow.Clients.TryGetValue(id, out client))
                {
                    state = client.State;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(random.Next(50));

                if (random.Next(100) % 90 == 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"killing {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}");
                    killThis = true;
                   lock (lockObject)
                {
                    mainWindow.Clients.Remove(id);
                }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void RunWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RunWork");
            Random random = new Random();
            Int32 index = -1;
            while (!killAll)
            {
                if (!mainWindow.Clients.Any())
                {
                    killAll = true;
                    break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                // edit: still need lock here as count can change in between
            Client client = null;
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                index = random.Next(0, mainWindow.Clients.Count);
                client = mainWindow.Clients[index];
            }
                Debug.WriteLine($"Changing {client.Name}");
                client.State = RandomString(9);                 
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Worker killed");
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting. Enter id or kill");

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                mainWindow.Clients.Add(i, new Client
                {
                    Name = $"Client {i:000}",
                    State = "Unknown"
                });
            }

            var worker = new Thread(RunWork);
            worker.Start();

            var threadList = new List<Thread>();
            threadList.Add(worker);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var thread = new Thread(RunChild)
                {
                    Name = $"Child {i:00}"
                };

                threadList.Add(thread);
                thread.Start();
            }

            while (!killAll)
            {
                var str = Console.ReadLine();
                if (str.Equals("kill", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    killAll = true;
                    break;
                }

                int enteredId = -1;

                if (int.TryParse(str, out enteredId))
                {
                    id = enteredId;
                }
            }

            foreach (var thread in threadList)
            {
                thread.Join();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("all dead");
        }
    }
}
```